# Ninject Circular Dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

there are 2 classes in wpf app

First class

```
public class Context1 : BaseContext
    {
        private readonly Page1 _page1;

        public Context1(Page1 page1)
        {
            _page1 = page1;
        }
}
```

Second class

```
public class Context2 : BaseContext
    {
        private readonly Page2 _page2;

        public Context2(Page2 page2)
        {
            _page2 = page2;
        }
}
```

Configuration

```
container = new StandardKernel();
container.Bind<Page1>().ToMethod(context => new Page1() { DataContext = container.Get<Context1>() });
container.Bind<Page2>().ToMethod(context => new Page2() { DataContext = container.Get<Context2>() });
```

on start stackoverflow exception appears, how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` requires a `Page` and the `Page` requires a `Context`, so it is a circular dependency. I would recommend refactoring some of the behaviors of each into standalone services so that at least one of them can get its dependencies from the services and break the circular reference.